# Why aren't my nimbus didImageLoad methods being called?

Tags: ios, nimbus-ios

I'm new to Nimbus. Right now my app is trying to retrieve 4 images via this code:

```
for (int i=minFoto; i<=maxFoto; i++) {

    NINetworkImageView* networkImageView = [self networkImageView];

    NSString *resourceURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@registration/rest/users/account_get_foto/%@?fotoId=%d", baseURL, ssid,  i];

    NSLog(resourceURL);

    [networkImageView setPathToNetworkImage:resourceURL
                             forDisplaySize: CGSizeMake(50, 50)
                                contentMode: networkImageView.contentMode];
```

I know my loop is working because I see all four NSLog's come out correctly. However, I am only getting the first image. networkImageViewDidStartLoad is only being called once and neither didLoadImage or networkImageViewDidFailLoad is being called. I think it is odd that didLoadImage is never being call. Never. I know I have the data because I'm using CharlieProxy (great app BTW, well worth the $50) and it shows the image data in the response packets.

So I commented this out of my delegate:

```
[[Nimbus networkOperationQueue] setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
```

And as you  might expect, I'm getting 4 calls to networkImageViewDidStartLoad, and still zero to didLoadImage or networkImageViewDidFailLoad.

Here are my request headers (from CharlieProxy)

```
GET /registration/rest/users/account_get_foto/fdbc2222-7b75-4ff4-b111-623e951e5b00?fotoId=134     HTTP/1.1
Host: -------------:8080
User-Agent: Ferret/1.0 CFNetwork/548.0.3 Darwin/11.2.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

and here's the response headers, showing a "200 OK"

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0; JBossAS-6
Content-Type: image/*
Content-Length: 461109
Date: Tue, 31 Jan 2012 21:12:33 GMT

âPNG (png data deleted...)
```

I'm a little puzzled now. My server is clearly returning the image data, but my app just isn't getting it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found it. Might as well put the answer in for future googlers.

My networkImageView had gone out of scope and was ARC'd. Funny, I thought I had saved it away, but that code was partially commented out!